# Using Pug to render a component variable that contains HTML code

Tags: html, angular, pug

Hi I have an Angular2 app, and in one of the components I have an attribute that I want to display. The problem I have is that I'm using Pug as my template engine and the attribute I'm trying to display contains HTML tags, how can I get Pug to interpret this code as its own syntax?

So for example I try to display something like this in my template:

`p {{attribute}}`

Where attribute is something like this:

`<h2>Sample Text.</h2>`

I've tried this `p #{attribute}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't a Pug problem and had to be resolved with Angular2 by adding `[innerHtml]` to the element:

`p([innerHtml]="attribute")`